# Replacing missing values by previous observation with conditions (R or SAS)

Tags: r, sas

I have persion-period dataset and I'm trying to create time dependent covariates.
Currently my data looks like this. Variables chg & help are just variables that I made while creating this data.

```
ID time status chg help parent married child 
1 0 P 0 . 0 0 0
1 1 P 0 . 0 0 0
1 2 P 1 . 0 0 0
1 3 M 0 P 1 0 0
1 4 M 0 . 0 0 0
1 5 M 0 . 0 0 0
1 5 M 0 . 0 0 0
2 0 P 0 . 0 0 0
2 1 P 1 . 0 0 0
2 2 L 0 P 1 0 0
2 3 L 0 . 0 0 0
2 4 L 1 . 0 0 0
2 5 M 0 L 0 1 0
2 6 M 0 . 0 0 0
```

I'm trying to 'save' these covariates (parent child married) so that for example if at time t=3 parent=1 then at time t=4 (and to the end of follow up), parent-variable should remain at parent=1.

So the correct data should look like this

```
ID time status chg help parent married child 
1 0 P 0 . 0 0 0
1 1 P 0 . 0 0 0
1 2 P 1 . 0 0 0
1 3 M 0 P 1 0 0
1 4 M 0 . 1 0 0
1 5 M 0 . 1 0 0
1 6 M 0 . 1 0 0
2 0 P 0 . 0 0 0
2 1 P 1 . 0 0 0
2 2 L 0 P 1 0 0
2 3 L 0 . 1 0 0
2 4 L 1 . 1 0 0
2 5 M 0 L 1 1 0
2 6 M 0 . 1 1 0
```

Any help with R or SAS are truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `R`, we can get the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) of the variables of interest after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, (6:8) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), ID, .SDcols = parent:child]
df1
#    ID time status chg help parent married child
# 1:  1    0      P   0    .      0       0     0
# 2:  1    1      P   0    .      0       0     0
# 3:  1    2      P   1    .      0       0     0
# 4:  1    3      M   0    P      1       0     0
# 5:  1    4      M   0    .      1       0     0
# 6:  1    5      M   0    .      1       0     0
# 7:  1    5      M   0    .      1       0     0
# 8:  2    0      P   0    .      0       0     0
# 9:  2    1      P   1    .      0       0     0
#10:  2    2      L   0    P      1       0     0
#11:  2    3      L   0    .      1       0     0
#12:  2    4      L   1    .      1       0     0
#13:  2    5      M   0    L      1       1     0
#14:  2    6      M   0    .      1       1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

In `SAS`, you can use `RETAIN` and `LAST.varible` to get the cumulative sum.

```
Data origin_dataset;
    infile 'Your raw data folder';
    input ID time status $ chg help $ parent married child;
Run;

Data temp;
    Set origin_dataset;
    By ID;
    Retain parent_t married_t child_t;
    parent = SUM(parent_t, parent); parent_t = parent;
    married = SUM(married_t, married); married_t = married;
    child = SUM(child_t, child); child_t = child;
    If LAST.ID = 1 Then DO;
        parent_t = 0;
        married_t = 0;
        child_t = 0;
    END;
Run;

Proc print data = temp (drop = parent_t married_t child_t);
Run;
```